# Problem with function who contain gtk GSList

Tags: c, gtk

im creating a pretty simple GUI in c using gtk +-3 . I got issues with the GSList : I try to get the last element in a GSList and destroy it just after , for that im using this code :

```
pBoiteAncienne = (GtkWidget*) g_slist_nth_data(lAbsolute, LastGslistElement(lAbsolute));
    gtk_widget_destroy (pBoiteAncienne);
```

Where LastGslistElement is this function :

```
int LastGslistElement(GSList *list)
{
    int n;
    n = g_slist_length (list);
    n--;

    return n;
}
```

I use this type of code two times in my programs , the first time no bug happen and it all goes right , but the second time i handle a crash . Here's the code that don't bug :

```
pBoiteAncienne = (GtkWidget*) g_slist_nth_data(lAbsolute, LastGslistElement(lAbsolute));
    
    gtk_widget_destroy (pBoiteAncienne);
```

Obviously this function depends on what is the last GSList elements and in the two times its a gtkbox:
The non-buggy last element

```
pBoiteTotal = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pWindow), pBoiteTotal);
lAbsolute = g_slist_append(lAbsolute,(GtkWidget*) pBoiteTotal);
```

The buggy last element

```
pBoiteHome = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 50);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pWindow), pBoiteHome);
    lAbsolute = g_slist_append(lAbsolute,(GtkWidget*) pBoiteHome);
```

Comment: If you [Prepend](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html#g-slist-prepend)   (instead of append)  the LIST first and then just after you [Reverse](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html#g-slist-reverse) it? Does happens the same?

Comment: By the way, I am strongly suggesting you that [you read This](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/tutorials/l-glib/)

Comment: At the moment of the declaration are you setting your list to NULL =>> GSlist *lAbsolute = NULL?

Comment: Thanks for the guide and yes , the List is declared NULL at the start

Comment: By the way, drop the C casts and work with GTK macros.  Change this =>> “ (GtkWidget*) pBoiteHome” to this =>>. “GTK_WIDGET(pBoiteHome)” and so on... There  is a good reason why we have things like “GTK_IS_WIDGET( object )” in GTK.

Comment: Okay , can you briefly explain why ?